# How does marginalizing over one variable affect independencies in the distribution?

Tags: independence, bayesian-network, marginal-distribution

I was requested to find a general algorithm which, given a Bayesian network graph $\mathcal{G}$ over a set of random variables  $\mathcal{X}$ and a node to remove $X\in \mathcal{X}$, builds a new graph $\mathcal{G'}$ which is a minimal I-
Map for the distribution over $\mathcal{X}\backslash X$ obtained by marginalizing over $X$

Given a set of independence assertions, building an I-map is easy enough, but how to read off the independencies in the marginalized distribution?

All independence assertions are of the form 
$$A\perp B\mid C$$
For $A,B,C\subseteq\mathcal{X}$

I figure that if $X$ is not in neither $A, B$ or $C$ marginalizing over it should not affect the independence, if $X\in A$ then we should have 
$$A\backslash\{X\} \perp B\mid C$$
But how do I handle the case where  $X\in C$?